# Is this data access pattern thread-safe?

Tags: database, go, global, go-gorm

I've implemented `dao.go` file with the following realization:

- `type DbClient struct {
      db *gorm.DB
  }`
- `GetDBClient()` initializes connection with database and returns `(*DbClient, error)`
- `func (db *DbClient) Close() {
      db.db.Close()
  }`
- Different CRUD methods of `DbClient`

And the `main.go` file that serves all the handlers consumes it like this:

```
var dbClient *DbClient

func main() {
    db, err := GetDBClient()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    dbClient = db
    defer dbClient.Close()
    ...
}
```

So all the handlers of the `main.go` use global `dbClient`.
Is this architecture thread safe and does it provide atomicity of operations with database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design should be good.

`sql.DB` handles concurrent access and implements pooling. `gorm` inherits these features from it.

One change I would made though. Global variables are hard to manage.
You can inject `db` into your code that uses it.

```
// to be removed
// var dbClient *DbClient

func main() {
    db, err := GetDBClient()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    CodeThatUsesDB(db)
    ...
}
```